# VB Property not being set when setting it from another form

Tags: vb.net, forms, properties

So I have a property Column Widths which i use to store the column index and the column width so when I reload my form my column widths persist (refresh function), that part is working 100%.

```
''' <summary>
    ''' Stores the widths of the columns on the form. 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Property ColumnWidths As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
        Get
            Return _columnWidths
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer))
            _columnWidths = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

But when i change the columns that are displayed (when i am on my options form), i want to clear the property. This is where the issue lies.

`Form1.ColumnWidths = Nothing`

I have tried using a public variable, this does not work either. Funny part is that i have used properties etc across my entire solution and that all works 100% but this is just grinding my gears for the reason why it is not retaining the value when i set it from my options form.

I even have a property on Form1 that doesnt have the Get Set parts and that works fine when i set it from the options form. Yet this property does not want to be set.

Both forms are within the same namespace and it does fire off the set part to the property but the _columnWidths value remains unchanged. it still has the rows in which i added to the collection.

Comment: It sounds like `Form1` is the name of the form's class, not the instance of the class that is being shown. pass the instance of `Form1` to the options form and use that instead of `Form1` to access the form.

Comment: Thanks @Blackwood, that helped me. I got it to work by adding the Shared setting on the property.
`Public Shared Property ColumnWidths As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)`

now it has changed from using the form to using the class which is working :). thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the property to Shared allowed the Options form to access the Form1 class instead on the form.

```
''' <summary>
''' Stores the widths of the columns on the form. 
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Shared Property ColumnWidths As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
    Get
        Return _columnWidths
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer))
        _columnWidths = value
    End Set
End Property
```